# syntax Error: Unxpected token < in JSON as position 0

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I am having trouble in getting data using ajax. During my testing in local it returns exactly what i wanted but when i publish the project in the server with IIS, it return a HTML Code of my page and with an error "syntax Error: Unxpected token < in JSON as position 0". Can anyone help me. i really appreciate it. Thanks :)

Below are my code:

```
Controller: 
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult getregion(string zname)
    {
        SelectList list = RegionList(zname);

        var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented,
          new JsonSerializerSettings
          {
              ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
              NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
          });

        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The code above will return a list of region in JSON format.

```
public SelectList RegionList(string zname)
    {
        CustomerModel cust = new CustomerModel();
        List<SelectListItem> regionname = new List<SelectListItem>();
        try
        {

            dt1.Clear();
            MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(conn.getconnections("mysql"));
            mycon.Open();
            if (zname == null || zname == "")
            {
                cmdsql = mycon.CreateCommand(); cmdsql.CommandText = "SELECT regionname FROM tbl_region WHERE STATUS=1 group by regionname order by regionname asc";
            }
            else
            {
                cmdsql = mycon.CreateCommand(); cmdsql.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT regionname FROM tbl_region WHERE STATUS=1 and zonecode='{0}'  group by regionname   order by regionname asc", getzonecode(zname));
            }
            drsql = cmdsql.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                if (drsql.HasRows)
                {
                    regionname.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "- Select -", Value = "", Selected = true });
                    regionname.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "All Region", Value = "AllRegion" });
                    while (drsql.Read())
                    {
                        regionname.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = drsql["regionname"].ToString().ToUpper().Trim(), Value = drsql["regionname"].ToString().ToUpper().Trim() });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { cust.WriteToFile(ex.ToString()); return null; }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { cust.WriteToFile(ex.ToString()); }
        return new SelectList(regionname, "Value", "Text");
    }
```

This a method being called in getting the list of region.

```
 JAVASCRIPT:
 $(function () {
    $('#zoneitem').change(function () {
        var item = $('#zoneitem').val();
        var region = $("#regionitem");
        region.empty();

        if (item != "") {
            $("#reportsitem").val($("#reportsitem option:first").val());
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Home/getregion",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { zname: item },
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    region.append('<option value="' + result[i].Value.trim() + '">' + result[i].Text.trim() + '</option>');
                }
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);                    
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my _reference.js code, when i debug this the returned result was in html format of my web page. Please, can anyone help me with this problem. I research it already and tried it but still the same problem.

Comment: it seems that there is some html character in your response from api.. check if it contains any warning or notice for a variable and try to strip out all html chars and then parse response using JSON.parse(data)

Comment: Open the network tab and check the response payload.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why your response is resulting into html format.

1. The URL of your ajax request does not exist and thus resulting in 404 Not Found Error
2. The user id with which you are testing is not authorized to access the server resource resulting in 401 Unauthorized Error
3. Your ajax request is getting blocked by a firewall resulting in 403 Forbidden Error
4. Your server side code is dumping resulting in 500 Internal Server Error

There can be more scenarios but assuming your problem is point no. 4 above, the response you might be getting will be something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
        <p>The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and     
        was unable to complete your request.</p>
        <p>Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@example.com 
        and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you 
        might have done that may have caused the error.</p>
        <hr>
        <address>Apache Server at xyz.com Port 80</address>
    </body>
</html>
```

You are getting syntax Error: Unxpected token < in JSON as position 0 because the JSON parser is reading "<" of "<html>" in the response which is an invalid JSON.

As @torazaburo has mentioned in his comment, check the exact response in your network tab and based on the message, make corrections in your server side code.

Comment: This sounds like a comment, which shouldn't be posted as an answer. But if you edit it into a statement it will be an answer and most likely the correct one.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen you are right. I however do not have enough credits to comment on a question.

Comment: Yes, that's why it's better to edit this into an answer since it is a good answer to the problem.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen & VDWWD, I have edit my original answer to comply with stackoverflow guidelines. Thanks for your advice. jwpfox thanks for editing my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I already figure out the problem of my code. it has something to do with my js file. In URL Line, my server side it cant locate the folder name of my application. It will redirect to Controller.

Instead of https://my ip address/my folder application. It became like this https://my ip address/Home/getregion. in which it redirect to my controller.

So, I change it like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: " my folder application /Home/getregion",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { zname: item },
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                region.append('<option value="' + result[i].Value.trim() + '">' + result[i].Text.trim() + '</option>');
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);                    
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help me why it can't locate my application folder? Thank you a lot :)